# pointer pointing to an entire array

Tags: c, arrays

```
struct grid {
    int width, height;
    void *cells[];
};
typedef struct grid grid;

int main(){
    enum { width = 2, height = 10 };
    grid *g = malloc(sizeof(grid) + width * height * sizeof(void *));
    void *(*cells)[10] = &g->cells;
}
```

My professor taught us about this cool way to allocate a flexible array and then assign a pointer that points to an entire array of pointers

`void *(*cells)[10] = &g->cells;` <-- This line

So i tried this method

```
 char *array[10];
 char *(*pointer)[2] = &array;
```

And it just gave me a compiler error

```
warning: incompatible pointer types initializing
      'char *(*)[2]' with an expression of type 'char *(*)[10]'
       [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       char *(*pointer)[2] = &array;
```

If anyone could explain to me the functionality of a "pointer to an entire array" 
that would be useful. Thank you

Comment: when you say "gave me a compiler error" in a question, you should *always* include the error.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for reminding

Comment: The array length is part of the type.  `char *(*pointer)[2]` is a pointer to 2-element arrays of `char *`.  Maybe `char *(*pointer[2])[10]` to get a 2-element array of pointers to 10-element arrays of `char *`?

Comment: If your professor said that, he was wrong.  He might declare `cells` field as `char cells[0];`, not as an incomplete type definition, which is probably the cause of compiler complainting, as the compiler cannot know `sizeof struct grid` as there is an incomplete type defined there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take your correct declaration first:

> ```
> void *(*cells)[10] = &g->cells;
> ```

To understand this, recognize first that `cells` is the identifier being declared, and from there follow precedence rules:

1. `(*cells)` says that `cells` is a pointer, and the rest of the declaration describes the pointed-to thing.  The parentheses are simply to enforce precedence, just like in an arithmetic expression.
2. The `[10]` applies next, because brackets have higher precendence than unary `*`.  This says, then, that `(*cells)` is an array with 10 elements.
3. That leaves the `void *` out front, which gives the type of each element.

And if we look at `&g->cells`, it is a pointer to an array of an unspecified number of `void *`.

Now consider your code:

> ```
> char *array[10];
> char *(*pointer)[2] = &array;
> ```

Following similar procedure, we get that `pointer` is declared as a pointer to an array of 2 `char *`.  So far, so good.  Now, what are you trying to assign to it?  Why, it's a pointer to an array of **10** `char *`.  That's a pointer to a different, incompatible type.

In the first case, the initializer's type is a pointer to an "incomplete type" that is compatible with the type to which the pointer points.  (It is incomplete because the array length is unspecified; it is compatible because in all other respects it matches the other type.)  The pointed-to thing *could be* an array of the length implicitly asserted by the assignment, and C will treat the pointer as if it were.

In the second case, C can see that the two pointers definitely point to objects of different size, and that therefore the assignment is definitely incorrect.  You would need a cast or a change to the type of `pointer` to make it accept the initialization.

Answer (score 3):

`&array` is the address of an array containing 10 pointers to char

`pointer` is a pointer to an array containing 2 pointers to char

`2 != 10`
,
hence the warning.

There's a handy [website](http://cdecl.org/) that helps to understand difficult c decelerations.